# What is the difference between an inaccuracy, a mistake and a blunder on lichess?

Tags: analysis, engines, blunder

I used lichess to analyse some of my games (lichess.org -> tools -> import game). It puts my bad moves (and those of my opponent) in one of three categories; "inaccuracy", "mistake" and "blunder". I guessed from the names (and the positions) that an inaccuracy is better than a blunder, but I wondered what the definitions were.

Comment: http://en.lichess.org/qa/75/how-are-these-determined-blunder-mistake-and-inaccuracy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Blunder: 300 centipawns

Mistake: 100 centipawns

Inaccuracy: 50 centipawns

This is sourced from http://en.lichess.org/qa/75/how-are-these-determined-blunder-mistake-and-inaccuracy

It is the first thing that appears when you google ["lichess inaccuracy mistake blunder"](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enAU604AU604&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lichess+inaccuracy+mistake+blunder).

Comment: This information seems to be removed from their FAQ and no longer appears when googled. Thanks for adhering to good Stack Exchange standards and including the answer here opposed to just the link